# C# ошибка CS0103

Tags: c#

Только сегодня начал изучать C#, и вот столкнулся с ошибкой `CS0103`, Имя "а" не существует в текущем контексте. Гугл решение не рассказал, на удивление.

```
using System;

namespace C_Sharp

{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi! Type your name here: ");
            try
            {
                int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't convert");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Thanks, {a}!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `a` у вас определена внутри блока `try`. Вне его она не видна.

Можно весь код поместить внутри блока:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi! Type your name here: ");
    try
    {
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine($"Thanks, {a}!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't convert");
    }
}
```

Или определить `a` до блока `try-catch`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi! Type your name here: ");
    int a;
    try
    {
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't convert");
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Thanks, {a}!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```